# How to turn off logs from winston for jest

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs

Currently I am testing a NodeJS app using jest. Particularly the system looks like this:

- NodeJS v13.4.0
- Jest 25.4.0
- [winston@next 3.2.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston)

When I run tests, I like the log to be ordered. Especially at the first test and then dig into the logs. I know, that jest has the option `--silent`. Funnily this option does not apply to winston. The source code of winston looks like it is trying to directly write to stdout/err.

Does somebody know, how I can get winston to be silent while tests are running with the `--silent` option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can utilize [`setupFilesAfterEnv` jest option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array), by pointing it to a file that will mock `console`. for instance

add this to `jest.config.js`:

```js
{
  ...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./jest.setup.js"],
  ...
}
```

then create a file `jest.setup.js`

```js
global.beforeAll(() => {
  console.error = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {});
  console.info = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {});
  console.log = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {});
});
```

> The source code of winston looks like it is trying to directly write to stdout/err.

note that, since you configured winston to print to stdout\stderr, so the following advise above should do the trick. of course, you might wish to add an additional check for the `--silent` flag

otherwise, you can have a condition to [silence winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#creating-your-own-logger) by utilizing the `silent` property of winston transport

> silent: If true, all logs are suppressed

Comment: Sadly the approach to mute the console does not work for me. Although I will, like you said just try to silence winston using the logger config. I just thought, there is a simpler solution for that.

Comment: Yes. The problem obviously resided in the ```winston/transports/console.js``` file. In this file, winston writed to stderr, if this is available. Obviously on my machine this is the case. Otherwise it uses the console api.

Comment: `silent` worked for me, thanks. In a nutshell: `winston.createLogger({ silent: process.env.JEST_WORKER_ID !== undefined })`

Answer (score 3):

To turn off winston logs for your Jest tests a best practice is to use the `silent` property of transporters together with `NODE_ENV`, like so:

```js
var transporters = [new winston.transports.Console()];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  transporters[0].silent = true;
}
```

This approach works with all types of transports and gives you full control over which transporters are muted in the tests and which are not.

**Note:** Jest will [set NODE_ENV to 'test' automatically](https://jestjs.io/docs/environment-variables). This behaviour is also useful for other test scenarios like loading test-configurations and so on.